# Automated script to add a comma between and organize ASCII values from a .txt file into rows?

Tags: python, automation

I have a list of 20,000+ ASCII values in a .txt file.
ie:

```
   2.4414063e-04
   3.0517578e-04
   3.6621094e-04
   4.5776367e-04
   5.4931641e-04
   6.4086914e-04
   7.3242188e-04
   8.2397461e-04
   9.1552734e-04
   1.0375977e-03
   1.1596680e-03
```

I need to add a comma immediately after each entry, also, I would like to organize the information in rows of 10. What is the best method for creating an automated Python script to do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  I'd think the split() and join() functions of strings would be a good start...

Comment: read the file, split the content, replace the \n's and write back in chunks of 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the `input_file` line by line, storing each value stripped of leading / trailing whitespace in a list.  When the length of the list is equal to 10, `join` all 10 elements into a string (separated by a comma and space). Append the string to `output_file`. Reinitialize the list to empty, and repeat until there are no more lines in `input_file`. After exiting the `for` loop that reads the lines in the file check if the list has any elements that need to be written to `output_file`. This would occur if the number of values / lines in `input_file` is not a multiple of 10.

```
# Read values from input_file and output as comma-separated values with 10 values per row
def process_input_txt_file(input_file, output_file):
    log.debug('Enter process_input_txt_file')

    # Create / overwrite existing output_file
    open(output_file, 'w+').close()

    # Store each value stripped of leading / trailing whitespace in a list
    value_list = []
    with open(input_file, 'r') as input_fh:
        for line in input_fh:
            value = line.strip()
            value_list += [value]

            if len(value_list) == 10:
                # Store the 10 values as a string, comma-separated
                value_row = '%s' % ', '.join(map(str, value_list))
                # Empty the list
                value_list = []

                # Write the string to output_file, on one line (row)
                with open(output_file, 'a') as output_fh:
                    print(value_row, file=output_fh)

        # Check if value_list contains any elements
        if value_list:
            # Store the remaining values as a string, comma-separated
            value_row = '%s' % ', '.join(map(str, value_list))
            # Write the string to output_file, on one line (row)
            with open(output_file, 'a') as output_fh:
                print(value_row, file=output_fh)
```

I tested this script with 100,001 values / lines and it took just under 3 seconds:

```
[2019-09-23 21:52:21,639] [main] Start example.py execution
[2019-09-23 21:52:21,643] [process_input_txt_file] Enter process_input_txt_file
[2019-09-23 21:52:23,931] [main] End example.py execution
```